# How do I hardcode a specific default time [ANDROID]?

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-datepicker, android-timepicker, android-date

I am setting some default hardcoded times. I am looking to hardcode 6pm as my default time. I have the code as follows:

```
Calendar mDate = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy");
mydatetime = mDate.getTime();
```

For mydatetime I was looking to hardcode 5pm as the date time, but not sure how to go about it? any ideas?

Comment: Are you aware of timezones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set time to `Calendar` object as below:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
```

**Use** `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` for 24 hour format.

**Or:** `Calendar.HOUR` for 12 hour format with `calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);` for setting AM or PM.

*In your case you can use as below:*

```
Calendar mDate = Calendar.getInstance();
mDate.set(Calendar.HOUR, 5);
mDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
mDate.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy, hh:mm a");
mydatetime = mDate.getTime();
```

Comment: do you happen to have any idea about one of my questions ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56012218/how-do-i-update-my-skeleton-layout-code-such-that-it-doesnt-block-my-viewpager